# Почему анимация transition дёрганная?

Tags: css, css3, анимация, transition

Почему у второй чёрточки анимация дёрганная? Я задал всем чёрточкам `transition: all 5s linear`, но вторая чёрточка при начале анимация очень резко повышает расположение по высоте,  в чём проблема?

```js
let header__burger = document.querySelector('.header__burger');

header__burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
 header__burger.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.header__burger {
 position: relative;
 background-color: black;
 border-radius: 2px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 35px;
 min-height: 36px;
 transition: margin-left .7s ease-in-out;
}

.line__burger {
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 100px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: white;
 transition: all 5s linear;
}

.line__burger:nth-child(1) {
 top: 30%;
 left: 18px;
}

.line__burger:nth-child(2) {
 transform: translateY(0%) translateX(0%);
}

.line__burger:nth-child(3) {
 top: 68%;
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger {
 top: 43%;
 height: 3px;
 width: 30px;
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(1) {
 transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(43%) translateX(3%);
 left: 13px;
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(2),
.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(3) {
 transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(43%) translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header__burger">
 <div class="line__burger"></div>
 <div class="line__burger"></div>
 <div class="line__burger"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что ты так координаты просчитал. Если поменяешь на линейную, будет лучше.

Comment: Зачем вам изменять расположение второй линии, сделайте ее прозрачной.

Comment: @Qwertiy что значит линейную? Я такое не знаю

Comment: Вместо `ease-in-out` поставить `linear`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Анимируя такие свойства как `top`, `height`, `width` и тд, браузер много раз пересчитывает позицию элементов, отсюда и дерганная анимация.

```
.header__burger.active .line__burger {
    top: 43%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Что бы всё работало плавно, единственные два свойства которые стоит анимировать в css - это `transform` и `opacity`. Они применяются уже к отрисованным элементам.

```js
let header__burger = document.querySelector('.header__burger');

header__burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  header__burger.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.header__burger {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 36px;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line__burger {
  width: 20px;
   height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.line__burger:first-child {
  transform: translateY(0.6rem);
}

.line__burger:last-child {
  transform: translateY(-0.6rem);
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(2),
.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="header__burger">
  <div class="line__burger"></div>
  <div class="line__burger"></div>
  <div class="line__burger"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ух ты, спасибо большое, не знал этого

Comment: Вообще - да, но конкретно в этом случае проблема не в производительности перерасчёта координат. Хотя да, этот вариант получился более плавным, поскольку при трансформациях работает сглаживание, а там было более ступенчатое перемещение.